# Copy values from object1 to object2 using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have Person class

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonID { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public int InternalValue { get; set; }
}
```

And, this is my DTO class

```
public class PersonDto
{
   public int person_id { get; set; }
   public string full_name { get; set; }
}
```

I am using AutoMapper and AutoMapper.Attributes to perform the Mappings as shown as bellow;

```
[MapsTo(typeof(Person))]
public class PersonDto
{
   [MapsToProperty(typeof(Person), "FullName")]
   public int full_name { get; set; }
}
```

I have an API which accepts PersonDto and save into the database using Entity Framework. Note that the `InternalValue` is not available in the DTO class which is a secret value :).

**My question is;** 
Is there any possibility to copy the values from a `PersonDto` object to `Person` object using AutoMapper? I have found some similar questions but couldn't found a strait answer.

Thanks in advance and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Map from PersonDto to Person you need to configure the attribute to allow reverse configuration.

Change the attribute to look like this:

```cs
[MapsTo(typeof(Person), ReverseMap = true)]
```

this will allow to call AutoMapper for PersonDto -> Person, to see more you can check the README of the project [here](https://github.com/schneidenbach/AutoMapper.Attributes).

Comment: Just adding, Now I can call this to get the final results; Mapper.Map<PersonDto, Person>(personDtoObj, personObj);

Answer (score 1):

Just to extend on the previous answer, if you are mapping through your `automapper congif` file or `code` , you could do:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDto,Person>().ReverseMap();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I like to use the AutoMapper.Attributes library so I can write the mapping details in the class definition itself.